# How do you calculate the weight capacity of a shelf?

Tags: shelving

I have a shelf that is about 4 feet long 2 feet wide and 1 1/2 inch thick. I would like to place an item on it that weighs about 90 pounds. I want to know if it will hold that and I don't know how to calculate it.

Comment: What is the shelf made of , how is it anchored to the wall or supported from the floor. Much more information will be needed.

Comment: Assuming proper support at the ends, I'd happily stand on that shelf if made of a normal wood species, (not balsa) and I weigh a lot more than 90 lbs....

Comment: A 1 1/2 inch thick shelf will laugh at 90 pounds all day every day. Your real concern is whether the shelf itself is properly anchored to support 90 pounds. A picture would be nice.

Comment: What type of wall will you be mounting this switch on?

Comment: We need to know what the shelf is made out of and how it's hung on the wall.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a piece of wood like that is going to weigh a significant fraction of 90 lbs, itself. You need to worry more about your supports and connection points than the wood.

Answer (score 2):

There is a cool site for this:  The "sagulator" for computing this. It's intended more for freespan shelves (like a book case), but you might be able to use it to answer your question.  Hope it meets your needs. Ed makes a good point about support as well. With that weight it will need to be fastened to studs with multiple brackets.

Edit:  Forgot the link, here it is:  https://www.woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/

Comment: The "I forgot the attachment" of the forum world? lol